# How can I get the apk file of an app?

Tags: applications, pdf, ebooks, documents

A while ago, I asked [a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138223/convert-android-app-ebook-to-pdf) which has been deleted by Community

> Some Android apps are in fact ebooks. For example, [Learn Lisp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tdt.learnlisp&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlearn%20lisp%20app&pcampaignid=APPU_14_RR7RVsXRHMXne4XNkqgE)
>
> Is it possible to convert android app ebook to pdf or some other document file types? Are there apps to
>   do that?

[Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) commented that:

> For this particular app: get the APK, open it with zip viewer, and
>   browse the `/assets` folder; they're in HTML files. I can't answer if
>   there's an automated way to convert it to PDF because the content
>   structure will not be the same for other apps.

[Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) commented that

> @AndrewT. good approach. You can add certain tweaks and I think it
>   would make a good answer, well at least for some apps, if not for all.
>   In Android, download busybox, get the APK, and then do `unzip -l APK_PATH | grep -E "FILETYPE$"`. If there exists a file with your
>   extension, its path in APK would be listed. If the developer went to
>   lengths to change the extension and hide the file, then this would
>   fail.

My questions are:

- How can I get the APK file of an app after installing it from Google Play?
- Once I find the APK file of an app, can I copy it out of my android phone to my Ubuntu laptop and then extract the hidden document file in the apk file? Or do I have to extract on my android phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I get the APK file of an app after installing it from Google Play?

Multiple ways, but the easiest one, I suppose, is to install a [backup type app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app%20backup&c=apps) such as [App Backup Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup). Take the backup of the the target app and its APK would be saved inside a directory under the default storage (*/sdcard*).

> Once I find the APK file of an app, can I copy it out of my android phone to my Ubuntu laptop and then extract the hidden document file in the apk file? Or do I have to extract on my android phone?

An APK is an archive (MIME type: application/zip). You can copy it to your laptop alike any multimedia file.

As for the extraction of the contents, there are [multiple apps on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=archive&c=apps) which supports extracting a ZIP file, so it is up to you to extract the app on Android or in your PC to explore its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Connect your phone to your desktop with usb. make sure your desktop have the adb utility and a suitable driver for your phone is installed.

1. `adb start-server` ; `adb devices´ ##make sure device is connected.
2. `adb shell pm list packages|grep -i "keyword"`  ##get the package full name, eg,my phone will get "package:com.sonyericsson.music" by running in  powershell>> adb shell pm list packages|grep  -i music
3. define the package's path "package:/data/app/com.sonyericsson.music-2/base.apk" by shell>> `adb shell pm path com.sonyericsson.music`
4. find the base.apk file in your working dir after running in shell>>`adb pull /data/app/com.netease.cloudmusic-1/base.apk`.

As the other guys say the apk file is actually a zip file, the extracting procedure seems easier.

Comment: Notice that `adb pull` expects two args, in the form `adb pull file/to/pull computer/location/to/place/it/in`.

Comment: if the dst folder is not provided, it defaults to the working dir.