# How to Find Where an App Is Installed? Find an App's Install Location

Tags: applications, file-system, file-management, folders

Usually, Android apps are installed in:

```
Internal shared storage/Android/​data/​app/​com.example.MyApp/​
```

However, I've been looking for a while but can't find where CapCut (the video editing app) is installed. Anyone know where CapCut is installed or how I can find its installation directory?

Comment: Sorry but you are totally wrong. Apps are never installed to the internal shared storage ( better known as `/sdcard` or `/storage/emulated/0`). Apps are installed to `/data/apps`. See also https://android.stackexchange.com/a/159070/2241 how to get the install path of an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps on the internal storage are stored under /data/app/.
Apps on external storage are stored as .asec files under the .android_secure folder.
System apps are stored under /system/app/.
The asec files are mounted under /mnt/asec but it may all vary a tiny bit depending on the version.
Try looking in each of these folders.

Comment: Do I need root access to view /data/app/? Because I'm not seeing it from my phone.

Comment: @GTSJoe Yes, you do.